# Qlik Sense - AGGR

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

fairly new to qliksense

this following expression works fine as a normal KPI.

```
Sum({$<RankNo = 

{"=rank(Only({$<OrderWeekFlag = {1}, [DeliveryDate] = {'>=$(=vMinDeliveryWeek)'}> 

+ 

<OrderWeekFlag = {1}>}RankNo))

<= 

$(=sum({$< [DeliveryDate]= {'>=$(=vMinDeliveryWeek)'} , OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}[HasOrder])) 

"},OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}

[HasOrder])
```

/ Sum(AGGR(sum({$< OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}[HasOrder]), [Department]))

I want it to work in a table , that has dimension of 'Department'

I understand I need to use something like  `SUM(AGGR(SUM(Cost), [DEPARTMENT]))`

but how use `SUM(AGGR(SUM`   ... in the expression below

```
Sum({$<RankNo = 

{"=rank(Only({$<OrderWeekFlag = {1}, [DeliveryDate] = {'>=$(=vMinDeliveryWeek)'}> 

+ 

<OrderWeekFlag = {1}>}RankNo))

<= 

$(=sum({$< [DeliveryDate]= {'>=$(=vMinDeliveryWeek)'} , OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}[HasOrder])) 

"},OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}

[HasOrder])
```

/ Sum(AGGR(sum({$< OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}[HasOrder]), [Department]))

I have tried with no joy

please help

Comment: Hi, can you give us a sample data table? and or explain what the expression is trying to calculate? My first instinct is that all that set analysis has removed the dimensionality that is required to make it work in a table but I don't understand the objective of the KPI

Comment: Hi - in the KPI it shows the overall percentage, I want to break this down by department across a table. I have added to the above the part I have working - using the aggr ... / Sum(AGGR(sum({$< OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}[HasOrder]), [Department]))   please help

Comment: It's still too complicated to read that first part of the expression and the Sum(AGGR(sum({$< OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}[HasOrder]), [Department])) part should be exactly equivalent to sum({$< OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}[HasOrder]) if the dimension is Department. If it isn't i would need to see the data model to understand why. Qlik does the aggregation over the dimension of the chart automatically

Comment: Hi here is an updated expression, as it does not appear very well in the question, because of the formatting Sum(Aggr(Sum({$<RankNo = 

{"=rank(Only({$<OrderWeekFlag = {1}, [DeliveryDate] = {'>=$(=vMinDeliveryWeek)'}> 

+ 

<OrderWeekFlag = {1}>}RankNo)), [Department]))

<= 

$(=sum(aggr(sum({$< [DeliveryDate]= {'>=$(=vMinDeliveryWeek)'} , OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}

"},OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}

[HasOrder]), [Department]))



/ Sum(AGGR(sum({$< OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}[HasOrder]), [Department]))
   ...please help

Comment: I want to help but I can't. Without example data and the goal of the expression I don't know what you are trying to achieve. Your syntax for what you are showing me is correct and will work, but I don't think it is solving the problem you think it is.

Comment: Most likely all those set statements are cancelling each other out and effectively doing very little for your expression. Like this portion, RankNo = {"=rank(Only({$<OrderWeekFlag = {1}, [DeliveryDate] = {'>=$(=vMinDeliveryWeek)'}> + <OrderWeekFlag = {1}>}RankNo) seems to be saying return me the set of results that have a RankNo equal to the rank of the things that have the OrderWeekFlag =1 and less than the vMinWeek including those that have an OrderWeekFlag=1.

Comment: I need statement that says something like; Please find the department with the most outstanding orders in the selected week